# Scrolling to element on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Nothing works. I tried this common solution for instance, nothing happens.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#id").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

That #id being a container.

Comment: Why don't you just use $('body').animate? Instead of document dom

Comment: Your code works for me...

Comment: @Manjunath Not sure what you're saying.

Comment: @Yaniv But not for me. I tried that alert thingy to test that jquery is loaded.